# Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to download Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 PatchSet 1 JRE but could not find it in oracle.com web site.

Could you please let me know the url from which I can download it.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean JDK here rather than JRE?

WebLogic Server 11gR1 uses JDK 1.6.0_21 (at least the version I downloaded a little while back did)

If you just want the Sun version of the JDK rather than JRockit, you can find it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-jsp-136632.html

Out of curiosity, why are you looking to download just the JDK and nothing else?